# Is it possible to change the destination page of a QR code?

Tags: google-play, app-store, qr-code

I'm not familiar with QR codes, but for an app I'm developing for both Android as well as IOs, I need a QR code that takes the user to the Google play or App store. I'm told that this QR code is already generated by somebody else working on the project, but the app is not yet in the stores, so the destination page does not yet exist. Right now this QR code links to nothing. Is it possible to assign this destination page later on, or do I need to generate a new QR code for this link?

Also, is it possible to have a QR code link either to the play store or app store depending on which device it's scanned with, without taking the user to an extra web page beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the tool you are using to generate this QRCode, you might be able to modify it later on and add the final Google Play URL.

If you want to have a single page that redirects depending on the device, you might be interested by [onelink](https://www.onelink.to/)

You can setup the landing page with multiple store IDs, then put this link as the callback of your QRCode, and you will be redirected to the right page depending on the device OS / platform.

I hope it will help you, I am using this for my projects and it is working really nice.

By the way, welcome to Stack!